# How to publish from a different repo in GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages

If I have an HTML project repo in GitHub, can I use my GitHub pages (which is a different repo) to publish it?

Is [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) applicable for my requirement?

Comment: The git pages for a project need to exist in the same repo. The article you linked to tell you possibilities. What you probably want is [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).

Comment: The pages is currently published on `master` branch. But how to link the other repo to the pages?

Comment: Link other repo to the pages. What do you mean by this? pages means branch or where you deploy?

Comment: you can have your (html) project on a repo, let's say in branch master, and your pages on the same repo, but in another branch. On your repository settings there's an option to select the branch where the git page is build from

Comment: Please note that Git is version control software, and GitHub is an online web service that uses Git; they are not the same thing. I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to clarify.